# PHPUnit-testing with anonymous functions

Tags: php, phpunit, slim, anonymous-function

Say I use a framework like Slim (PHP) and I have this pretty modern code structure:

```
$app->post("/", function($request, $response) {

    // define the post actions here

});
```

I could put the anonymous function into a separete class, but is there a way to write a test without loosing this code structure?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your question about writing unit test for that anonymous function? Or are you asking about something like integration test?

Comment: @nima "unit test for that anonymous function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some ways to test that. Regardless, I would recommend splitting each handler into it's own file (probably even a class, that has an __invoke method). The reason is that this way of defining handlers looks short and crisp now. But once you have more than 10 endpoints it gets really ugly to maintain and you're mixing routing logic together with different handlers.

If this is a very small project and you want to keep that kind of syntax, there are two strategies to test it. But be aware that both of them are going to be a bit more cumbersome than you might like:

**Integration Test Style (NOT recommended)**

you just call `$slim->run()` in your tests and check if the output of the handler fits your expectations. Slim offers a nice way to mock a http request [as you can find at the bottom of that page](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/cookbook/environment.html). Please be aware that you'll be limited to only check on the data that is returned from your handler. If your handler returns plain HTML, you can only check that the html returned contains the right things.

You could take this a bit further if you used slim's dependency injection feature and provided mocks to it.

**Simple Handler Style (recommended)**

Alternatively you can also keep your anonymous handler function in the routing but defer the handling of the actual business logic to another class, which you could then test. If your controller is very simple and does nothing but retrieve GET/POST parameters and forward them to a class, then there's not such a lot of testing to it.

Besides this giving you an angle to test, it's also a nicer way to think about seperation of concerns. Your slim handler function will take care of framework and HTTP basics, and you'll have a nice domain class that does not need to bother with this.

```
$app->post("/register", function() {
    $result = (new RegisterUserAction())
        ->register($_POST["email"], $_POST["password1"], $_POST["password2"]); 
    // now use $result to render the html page to show to the user
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test exactly this anonymous function, you can try to mock an `$app` variable:

```
$app = $this->getMockBuilder('app class')->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(['post'])
    ->getMock();
$app->method('post')->willReturnCallback(function ($url, $anonymousFunction) {
    // do some tests with $anonymousFunction
});
```